# Use Google Direction API result to display route in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, google-maps-api

I need to show route between 2 points in OpenLayers. I have received the route details from Google Directions API. The API has given start location / end location, Steps and overlay_polyline (encoded) data.

The overlay_polyline shows right path using url 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility' , but as this is encrypted I extracted coordinates from Steps array as lat/long and added a vector layer on OpenLayers map but in this way many points are left in between and road curvature is not considered.

Output of my API (which formats Directions API output):

```
{
  "end_address": "100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, CA 91608, USA",
  "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1358593,
    "lng": -118.3511633
  },
  "start_address": "1313 Disneyland Dr, Anaheim, CA 92802, USA",
  "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8160897,
    "lng": -117.9225226
  },
  "distance": {
    "text": "35.1 mi",
    "value": 56511
  },
  "duration": {
    "text": "49 mins",
    "value": 2924
  },
  "Locations": [
    {
      "lat": 33.8160897,
      "lng": -117.9225226
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.8160679,
      "lng": -117.9225314
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.8155824,
      "lng": -117.9235917
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.816278,
      "lng": -117.9242395
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.817613,
      "lng": -117.924097
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.8179964,
      "lng": -117.9235637
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.8179846,
      "lng": -117.9223305
    },
    {
      "lat": 33.8207878,
      "lng": -117.9230963
    },
    {
      "lat": 34.0256221,
      "lng": -118.2059515
    },
    {
      "lat": 34.1294658,
      "lng": -118.3475583
    },
    {
      "lat": 34.1307998,
      "lng": -118.3485738
    },
    {
      "lat": 34.1338819,
      "lng": -118.3515888
    },
    {
      "lat": 34.1358593,
      "lng": -118.3511633
    }
  ],
  "overview_polyline": {
    "points": "qukmEvvvnUz@l@\\n@H|@KvAI`BsB@Ee@O?e@BoAC_@H}@?_@??S?_@?ACCe@_@[OGm@BiEAs@_@Bm@HyEhAaC|@eCv@eF_BgB]wAHmAb@oJdIeCxB}@nAmI~H{JtKgOfPg@b@qDnGsAvDoAvEeC~PeBhKoAhEqDrIwa@b_AyCzGyBdEqFnJqB~DeFxMiOh_@gVdk@oCxEiD~EgDpEkHhKa@x@wAxDc@nBcDzNaDxNkCbIgFfL_JrOmG~M{MxZkN~ZgC`GiFjLaDpGgDzEkDbEiE|FqBlDgIzQoRlc@aIrQuEjK{CrGaD`GmDbHcCnG}GhNaUnj@kDhIwBrFaK|TkG`MqRp`@iEdJoC|GkBfE_GpL_FfIuFtH}GrHySlSuE|EmEjGgFjKwFxLeHfK{FrGqC|BmFvDyIvF}D`Cuu@be@ySvN{ThNe\\fRo]fSmR~KoNrIkDzCeCrC{I|Mu^xj@gSxZyAbBmC`C}AfA{DvBoC~@sNzC_L`CaFdAoEpAsHxDqM~IyCzBuCjCeGfGgShS{H`IyCnEoD~FyB~CgCfCkElEom@tk@{DjC}BhAmCvAqDjCkVbUsCvCoH`JuGjIuF~JeE`FwF`FgA`AcCvCkChFyBfG{JhY}AdFuAnHo@rCw@rBuBhEMTy@jBcMp^}BjH[pAqAjJWrI@zo@m@nJu@vEgAbEuJ~YkHrTsD`Lq@pC@h@}BzI}Mn`@wF~O}DjJqDzFoAzA]PiChC{C|BwBbAgFdAeDDsGk@qHTsEK_Dg@aKw@wJDuFRwCXqDr@gEtAoEjBsItDkBnBiAfCc@~Bg@bHyCp]a@|Ge@zKPtFWhCa@jBu@rBqChFoLrTgEjHyF`IoFbFgKpIeDrCkEbG_NzSaDnHcB`GkK~a@sFhQ_DlJwChJ_CfHkCtGmDfMqGx\\wE~ZuBlP_BjLwAbGiAzCkGzNmJnWcDlHcOxVeDbFcCrCqFjE{MdHwBjA_C`BiCpCoAnB_HhMcDnFkB|BqE`EcEfCuOvHsDlBkBxAiBrB{B~Dy@`Cs@zCa@pDKlFInGe@vEYtAwAfEeFxJ{M`XkDzGeAzAqDtD{AhAqAl@sCt@qLxCoRpDeErAmD`BaEbCqC~BqEzEaBnB}FnHmB|BkBdBsG|DcElDsFvFkCdCM?qBdB_ChB_IdFmDdFiA~@gA~ASBe@KiB_AcAU_BKo@@"
  }
}
```

There is a difference for other searches when I draw a line using locations array and using overview_polyline in the polylineutility. overview_polyline is accurate.

Is there a better way to show route in OpenLayersor? How can I use this overlay_polyline property in OpenLayers?

Comment: Found an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852268/c-sharp-implementation-of-googles-encoded-polyline-algorithm. Decoding code worked as expected !

Comment: If you are using OpenLayers `new ol.format.Polyline().readGeometry()` decodes a polyline directly to a linestring

Comment: Thanks ! I tried and this worked as expected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode polylines directly in OpenLayers to create a series of LineString features (which could be also combined as a single MultiLineString geometry)

```
result.routes[0].legs.forEach(function(leg) {
    leg.steps.forEach(function(step) {
        googleRouteLayer.getSource().addFeature(
            new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.format.Polyline().readGeometry(step.polyline.points).transform('EPSG:4326', viewProjection)
            })
        );
    });
});
```

You should not use Google routes on publicly accessible non-Google maps as the Google ToS prohibit it.

Comment: I used the steps returned from google api and pushed them in my locations array in the same order. Here the issue is like, if a road is straight but have a curve then the api given 2 end points as lat/long and not the intermediate point hence exact path is not followed. But the encrypted overline follows the same. I am using google API through my api using google key.

Comment: I need to show a path following the road for reach the destination.

Comment: I used below approach :   let l_data = this.FetchCoordinatesArrOL(argDirectionResponseModel.Locations);

      this._RouteDataLayer = new Vector({
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: [new Feature({
            geometry: new LineString(l_data).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            name: 'RouteLayer'
          })]
        }),
      });

      this.map.addLayer(this._RouteDataLayer);